# jQuery - How to add the attribute rel to multiple links?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

Here's my code so far:

```
$('#floorplans img').each(function() {
    $('#floorplans a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
    });
});
```

It works well so far, but I need it to do same thing for `#gallery` too. Is it possible to accomplish this without having to write the same code again for `#gallery`?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't see why you use a loop within a loop where a single loop would be enough.

Comment: Hi. Basically, I want to add the rel="lightbox" just to images within a link `<a href="big-photo.jpg"><img src="thumb-photo.jpg" /></a>`... Without the 2 loops, it adds the rel to all the links, right?

Answer (score 2):

Yes - use the [multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

Would

```
$('#floorplans img a, #gallery img a').attr('rel', 'lightbox');
```

not do?

Update: I had "IMG" and "A" back to front, should have been all "A" which contain "IMG" inside "#Div", like this:

```
$('#floorplans a:has(img), #gallery a:has(img)').attr('rel', 'lightbox')
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, this does work: `$('#floorplans a:has(img), #gallery a:has(img)').attr('rel', 'lightbox');`

Answer (score 1):

Without having seen your markup, something like this may work:

```
$('#floorplans img, #gallery img').each(function() {
    $('a').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
    });
});
```

HTH

Update:
I still don't think this is right,
you aren't using the elements youve selected in the outer loop so its redundant.
And I think you are setting the rel attr multiple times because of it.
I havent tried it but I think you should only be using one loop, where you select links that have an image.

```
$('#floorplans a:has(img), #gallery a:has(img)').each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
});
```

Comment: I have removed my own, similar answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can define function and use it, like:

```
var addRel = function(selector) {
    $(selector).each(function() {
        $(this).attr('rel','lightbox'); 
    });
};

addRel('#floorplans a');
addRel('#gallery a');
```